# rails development server for windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a recommendation for a rails web server to use for development on windows. I was happy with the default rails server until I had to handle two concurrent requests which it does not support (a page calls an internal rest service). I want to keep the "rails s" experience, so which is the simplest server that support my needs?

Comment: well i use webrick without a problem... btw you may want to refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/869305/922954)

Comment: @eveevans - I use whichever comes with rails, I just do "rails s" today. I prefer not to install anything complex

Comment: @aishwarya - isn't webrick the default that ships with rails? does it support multiple concurrent requests?

Comment: Did you try railsinstaller ? for windows? ( http://railsinstaller.org/ )

Comment: @YaronNaveh why you want to support concurrent request in development?

Comment: @eveevans - I don't see that the railsinstaller ships with any special server. Also my web site backend calls a rest service on the same site, so currently there is a deadlock. actually it is more complicated than that but bottom line is that I'm required to support concurrent requests

Comment: @YaronNaveh, indeed, webrick is the default one, and it does not support concurrent requests per se. You can use mongrel if you like, but really, you should not need concurrent requests on dev.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no Windows-compatible Rails web server that is multi-threaded or concurrent out of the box.

You will need to spawn multiple back-end servers (we use mongrel, you could use thin instead) and then use/configure a proxy server (we use nginx) in front of them to handle multiple requests concurrently on Windows.

[This blog post](http://www.beechtreetech.com/ruby-on-rails-thin-and-nginx-on-windows) describes setting up Thin and nginx on Windows, once running you can edit the nginx.conf to proxy to multiple thin instances/ports.

Comment: What about Apache w/ Passenger?

Comment: @Ryan - why don't you use thin as standalone? it should support that. I tried this but it sometimes hangs, probably due it it relying on even machine which is problematic on windows. Please explain me the rational of adding nginx. The link you send me explains how to setup the rails eco system from scratch (including RubyInstaller) but I already have rails so I'm affraid some of the redundant actions there will cause me trouble.

Comment: @Yaron - we have been deploying Windows-based Rails 1.x and 2.x setups since before Thin was available, don't currently have a significant reason to switch away from Mongrel.  Our apps don't support asynchronous processing yet, so we have to run multiple single-threaded servers and proxy. YMMV...